# How to draw an arrow between two figures ending in a specific location

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I have two figures (.pdf) side-by-side and would like to draw an arrow from the right
one to the left one, with the arrow head ending at a specific location in the
left figure. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \tikz[remember picture]{\node(figleft){\framebox{\parbox[c][3cm]{0.4\textwidth}{\hspace{3.5cm}\raisebox{2cm}{Figure 1}}}};}%
  \hfill
  \raisebox{10mm}{\tikz[remember picture]{\node(figright){\framebox[0.4\textwidth]{Figure 2}};}}%
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\draw[thick, stealth-] (figleft-|figleft.north) -- (figright-|figright.west);}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The arrow head should end at a specific location inside Figure 1 (say, where
the text "Figure 1" appears). I assume I'd need to somehow specify the
location of the node `figleft`. A crude idea was to place a node at the
location of "Figure 1" and then have the arrow drawn to that location. I
tried with `\tikz[remember picture]{\node at (-1cm,3cm) (anchor) {Anchor};}`
but the placement `(-1cm, 3cm)` didn't seem to be respected.

Comment: I think the question might benefit from adding a screenshot of the output of the MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems odd to put `\framebox` inside a node when almost the exact same thing is achieved by `[draw]`.  The only difference is `[inner sep]` vs. `\fboxsep`.  Also `(figleft-|figleft.north)` is equivalent to simply `(figleft.north)` etc.

More importantly, `\raisebox` raises the text by lowering the baseline.  So `[baseline=-10mm]` is equivalent to `\rasiebox{10mm){...}`.  Similarly, Figure 1 is 2cm above `(figleft.base)`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \tikz[remember picture]{\node[draw,minimum height=3cm,minimum width=0.4\textwidth](figleft){\hspace{3.5cm}\raisebox{2cm}{Figure 1}};}%
  \hfill
  \tikz[remember picture, baseline=-10mm]{\node[draw,minimum width=0.4\textwidth,anchor=south](figright){Figure 2};}
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{\draw[thick, stealth-] (figleft.base east) ++ (0,2) -- (figright.west);}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]